# how to properly throw an error inside switchMap?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I need to create a record with the condition that the email has not been used. To this end I try the following service:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { EMPTY, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { CustomerModel } from "@app/shared/models";
import { ContactsService } from "@app/project/contacts/services/contacts.service";
import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class CustomerService {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
    private readonly contactsService: ContactsService
  ) {}

  create(model: CustomerModel): Observable<CustomerModel> {
    return this.contactsService.verifyContactExists(model.contact.email).pipe(
      switchMap((value) => {
        if (!value) {
          return this.httpClient.post<CustomerModel>(this.urlEndPoint, model);
        }

        throwError("Email already exists");
      })
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```

The create method is handled in the component in a similar way to the following:

```
handler(): void {
  const action: Observable<any> = this.customerService.create(contact).pipe(
    map((result) => {
      this.contactList.push(result);
      return true;
    })
  );
}
```

After a brief logic the possible error is handled like this:

```
return action.pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    this.toastrService.error(error.error.message, "", {
      positionClass: "toast-top-right",
      closeButton: true,
      timeOut: 3000,
    });
    return of(false);
  })
);
```

The problem I am experiencing is that when identifying in the create method that the email has already been used and consequently calling `throwError('Email already exists');`, the behavior that no error is shown occurs and apparently throwError does not cause anything , it simply remains in an operation that never ends.

I am new to ngrx and am having trouble on how to properly handle these scenarios. I would appreciate your advice

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Afaik `throw new Error("some message")` is what you're looking for instead of throwError. At least that is what I use to throw errors in my observables.

Comment: Thanks Fy Z1K using `throw new Error("some message")` is solving my problem.